# Site down, "status":200 error?

Tags: php, jquery, http-status-codes

On an index.php page, I'm using a jQuery redirect in order to send users on smaller screens to a mobile login page. I'm using the .php extension, so it will be read FIRST. The site owner emailed me a screen-shot, saying the "site is down, getting this error"

The screen-shot revealed this:
{"status":200,"exec_time":8.34300000000000001e-06}

But then he emailed me back saying "never mind, I just restarted Chrome, now it's OK" I have no idea what that was about. Any insight would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<!DCOTYPE html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( (screen.width <= 600) ) { 
        window.location = '/mobile.html';
    }
    else if ( (screen.width > 600) ) { 
        window.location = '/index.shtml';
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you're not automatically redirected, please choose:</p>
<p><a href="mobile.html" target="_self" title="Mobile Login Page">Mobile Login Page</a></p>
<p><a href="index.shtml" target="_self" title="Desktop Login Page">Desktop Home Page</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your server was probably running through instabilities when the user sent you this message. There's probably nothing related with this issue in this code.

Comment: OK, interesting. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"status":200,"exec_time":8.34300000000000001e-06}`

Status 200: OK - This means the server accepted and handled your request without error

exec_time: probably how long the script took to execute it's relevant functions.

At first and second glance I still don't see any glaring problems with the posted code.
In any case it could be chrome simply had a hiccup on that specific local installation and failed to render the page correctly even when it successfully sent a request and received a good header response.

Either way the server produced a good header so unless you find something in (or post) your relevant logs that proves your server's state otherwise it might not be prudent to consider it a server error or a case where the site is 'down'.

Comment: Thanks Cristian, that's good to know (and information over my geek level, so it helps to learn). Cheers!

Comment: No worries @Greg Smith, if you feel that you have gotten the appropriate please consider choosing an answer to close the question or if you have any other questions please feel free to ask.